# How many photons can a free electron in a metal can interact with at an instant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

I know free electrons interact with multiple photons,But there should be a limit.What is the limit and why it interacts with that many photons,What factor decides the interaction between an photon and an free electron?.

Comment: "I know free electrons interact with multiple photons " do you mean with *virtual* photons? Virtual photons are under an integration continuum and in principle are infinite in number. for real photons an electron has to interact, i.e. pickup or give energy , and "multiple" is given by  the quantum mechanical probability distribution for brehmsstrahlung or synchrotron radiation

Comment: Not virtual photons.Suppose two similar  photons simultaneously incident on  a electron,does the electron interact with both photons simultaneously or with only one electron?.

Comment: within the metal the photons are virtual, as well as the fermi sea electrons. A real free electron can interact with two photons , there will be a Feynman diagram,  but the delta(t)  between the two photon -electron vertices  will be again within a integration, the "instant" has no meaning, because vertices do not overlap mathematically, in the integral. The order also has no meaning because there will be two diagrams .

Comment: You can only say that one ore more photons interact with a many-electron state.